# DIV changes position on page zoom

Tags: html, css, web

after reading similar questions on stackoverflow, nothing seemed to solve this problem. Here it is..

---

I have an DIV at the top of my page that I use as a menu. Dimensions are 1920px by 50px. And the CSS code for it is:

```
#top_bar{height:50px; width:1920px; margin:0px auto;
background:url("img/top_bar.png"); left:0px; top:0px; position:relative;}
```

I then have a content #wrapper DIV under that which is 960px wide and is centered. The CSS code for it is:

```
#wrapper{width:960px; margin:0px auto; overflow:hidden; left:0px; top:0px;
position:relative;}
```

When I zoom in on the page, the content #wrapper DIV stays in the correct position (centered), but the #top_bar DIV moves to the right.

---

The HTML code of the page is:

```
<body>

<div id="top_bar">
    (...menu links, etc)
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
    (...page content)
</div>

</body>
```

---

I'm in the process of fixing this for a client so any solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: It still does the same even if I change it to: position: absolute; or position: fixed; Even if I leave it blank. Is there a workaround to this? Thank you.

Comment: You should use floats and display them in an inline block.

Comment: Thanks @BuddhistBeast both display: block; and display: inline-block; worked.

Comment: Only thing is, now when I zoom in, the whole page zooms in to the left. Is there a way to make it zoom in to the middle or is that all that's possible?

Comment: its possible.. give me a sec to create fiddle for you son

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jeCnd

Answer (score 0):

It does not shift, it looks like it does only because the width of `1920px` extends well past the margins of your screen. The other div is much smaller.

If you want both divs to appear equally aligned you must give them the same widths

Comment: Thanks, but if I do that, when I zoom in, the whole page still zooms in to the upper left corner instead of zooming in to the middle. Also the menu items on the top bar wrap around onto a new line under where they are supposed to be when I zoom in instead of staying in their position.

Comment: Thanks the page Zooms in to the middle now but the top bar div still moves or "shears" to the right.

Comment: How about now? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gJEwc is that what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve centered positioning you have to do it with dynamic divs.

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/nukec/eh9DJ/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="side-pannel" id="left-pannel"></div>
<div id="container">
    <div class="two-item-column">
        <div class="item1 column-border-middle">1</div>
        <div class="item2 column-border-middle">2</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="side-pannel" id="right-pannel"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 88%;
    height: 580px;
    float: left;
}
.side-pannel {
    position: relative;
    width: 6%;
    height: 580px;
    float: left;
}
.two-item-column {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.column-border-middle {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.item1 {
    height: 288px;
    background: #ccc;
}
.item2 {
    height: 291px;
    background: #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

If you zoom in on an element whose size is fixed, it's going to get bigger, obviously. Unless it gets wider than the viewport in which case it has no choice but to expand to the right.